# PreparedStatement query to insert data into specific columns in a table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert data into specific columns (5th and 6th) of a table.
My `PreparedStatement` code is as follows:

```
PreparedStatement pst1  =  connection.prepareStatement("insert into CustomerPayment (End_Time,Paid) values (?,?) where PC_Used ='"+cmbpcname.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'");  
pst1.setString(5,lblendtime.getText());
pst1.setString(6,lblamount.getText().substring(3,5));
pst1.execute();
```

Is this query right? I am getting an error running that query. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: Please provide the error text

Comment: The first argument of `setString` and the other `set`-methods tell the implementation which `?` placeholder you would like to replace within your prepared statement. As your prepared statement contains only two placeholders, you're getting an exception that you attempt to replace placeholders that don't exist. I assume that `End_Time` and `Paid` are your fifth and sixth column respectively. You therefore just have to use `setString` on placeholder 1 and placeholder 2 and not on placeholder 5 and 6. Also your column and variable names suggest that numeric types would be more appropriate.

Comment: Your query wouldn't work, inserts don't have a where-clause.

Comment: The `INSERT` statement doesn't have a `where` clause. Are you looking for the `UPDATE` statement? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-update.html

Comment: Others have addressed your actual problems. I just want to echo @nikitoz and say ***always always always*** provide the error text and a stack trace. Saying "I'm getting an error" and leaving at that never works. We cannot see your screen and have little interest in running your code (unless your problem seems really interesting).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for ur help and i will keep in mind next time...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks a lot and yea that was my mistake of using insert statement i changed it to update statement as per ur suggestion and it worked smoothly...

Comment: @nikitoz next time onwards i will keep in mind to provide with error texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PreparedStatement pst1  =  connection.prepareStatement("Update CustomerPayment SET End_Time= ? , Paid = ? where PC_Used ='"+cmbpcname.getSelectedItem()+"'");  
            pst1.setString(1,lblendtime.getText());
            pst1.setString(2,lblamount.getText().substring(3,5));
            pst1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You should also use a parameter in your where condition, and not concatenate a value into it. Concatenating values into the query string is open to SQL injection, and usually less efficient than using parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The index refers to position in your statement not table. So,

```
pst1.setString(1,lblendtime.getText()); 
pst1.setString(2,lblamount.getText().substring(3,5));
```

should work.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion it helped for my second mistake.first very importantly was using wrong sql statement which in my case was "insert ".... i used update statement and all went smooth... :D

Comment: ok, and for your WHERE clause you could also use this:
`pst1.setString(3, cmbpcname.getSelectedItem().toString());`
if it is `...where PC_Used = ?`

Comment: @ Würgspaß  ok got it !!